# Read text file and make a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to read a text file and make a 2D array from it and I am not familiar with the 2D array. SO any help much appreciated My text file contains all the numbers.

I also tried with for loop but I was getting the same error.

Please review my code effort here

```
  Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("ELEVATIONS.txt"));
            rowLength = readFile.nextInt();
            colLength = readFile.nextInt();
            Radius = readFile.nextInt();

            int[][] data = new int[rowLength][colLength];

            System.out.println("ROW : " + rowLength + " COl : " + colLength + " Radius : " + Radius );

            int row = 0;
            while (readFile.hasNextInt() && row < data.length) {
                for (int col = 0; col < colLength; col++) {
                    data[row][col]= readFile.nextInt();
                }
                row++;
            }
```

When I run the code it gives me below **Error**

> ROW : 1000 COl : 450 Radius : 10 data 1000450 Exception in thread
>   "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>   lab1.Lab1.main(Lab1.java:43)

Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, my English not that much good I understand your point Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way is to read all integers from a file and fill 2D array using counters:

```
public static int[][] readFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        int rows = scan.nextInt();
        int cols = scan.nextInt();

        int[][] res = new int[rows][cols];

        for (int row = 0, col = 0; row < rows; ) {
            res[row][col++] = scan.nextInt();

            if (col == cols) {
                row++;
                col = 0;
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "2D array" code looks fine, you prepare the "empty" array, and you loop according to its dimensions.

The essence of your problem manifests here:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862) at

The point is: **while** reading the file you end up with an error. That has nothing to do whether you would only *print* the values to the console, or whether you store them in that pre-defined array.

In other words: at this point, your problem is that your file content does **not** match your expectations/assumptions. Thus you ask for a number ... where there is none.

The answer: step back. Start with a really small file that only contains say  `2 2 5 1 2 3 4`. Now, run your code with that, and then *print* every relevant information (for example the value read from the file). So that you **understand** what exactly your code is doing.

In other words: debugging is required. Either by actually using a debugger, or by adding print statements. You need to be able to observe your code doing its work.

Comment: Thank you GhostCat for the reply but my friend is using the same file and he got the proper output instead of the error.

Comment: @ArpitPatel You should be around long enough to understand: A) do not link to other sites for relevant content (as your file link, which btw: is already not working for me) B) so, if you want us to run your code, provide a **real** [mcve], something that works out of the box. Beyond that, I stand to my word: your array code is fine, and that exception is about an "unexpected" file read. As said: start with a small file, and debug what is happening. C) dont expect people here to do that for you ... we help you solving your issue, we dont necessarily solve it *for* you.

Comment: I just wanna know what's the reason behind it and yes I tried with small amount of data it's working fine. but later on, I wanna to do some operation on that data so need that And I didn't expect to code for me I just want help  @Ghost

Comment: @ArpitPatel When a small file works, then go step by step with more data. Again: this is basic debugging stuff. And as said: I am still convinced that something is wrong about your data. What else do you expect us to tell you? Two people tell you that yep, looks like a flaw in your data. But without that data and a true [mcve], nobody can repro your problem. So as said: what else should we be able to tell you?

Comment: I understand your point @Ghost but I need to find lowest value from that data and I need to show that to my professor so if I am getting this error then how should I show the lowest value from there and how many times it occurs and what position? that I wanna figure out.Because this is my assignment from college.

Comment: @ArpitPatel Again: then start by **printing** the values you read to the screen. Then you will quickly notice "where" exactly your code will stop, and what the last inputs were that it consumed. As said: that is what **debugging** is all about.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is mostly because your text file does not contain the element your code is trying to fetch.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // pass the path to the file as a parameter
        File file =

                new File("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Documents\\test.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        int rowLength = 0;
        int colLength = 0;
        int radius = 0;

        rowLength = sc.nextInt();
        colLength = sc.nextInt();
        radius = sc.nextInt();

        int[][] data = new int[rowLength][colLength];
        System.out.println("ROW : " + rowLength + " COl : " + colLength + " Radius : " + radius);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colLength; ++j) {
                if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    data[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }

        // printing the array
        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++) {
                System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]
My text file content-
2
2
5
1
2
3
4

Comment: Thank You Subham for the reply I added my text file please check it.

Comment: @ArpitPatel The link you shared seems to be broken

Comment: ops sorry I gonne fix that.